# touchend trigger many times

Tags: javascript, touch-event

I've written a slider component demo in mobile web.The event of a touched trigger once when I first swipe, but the second time you swipe,'touchend' triggers twice, and the third time, it's triggered three times. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>test touch</title>
    <style>
    body { margin: 0; }
       .box { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
       ul,li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
       ul { width: 500%; overflow: hidden; transition: .5s; }
       li { width: 20%; float: left; }
       li { font-size: 40px; color: #fff; text-align: center; line-height: 150px; }
       li:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange; }
       li:nth-of-type(2) { background: red; }
       li:nth-of-type(3) { background: pink; }
       li:nth-of-type(4) { background: green; }
       li:nth-of-type(5) { background: #333; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <ul id="test">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    function Slider(id) {
        var _this = this;
        this.wrap = document.getElementById(id);
        this.slider = this.wrap.getElementsByTagName("li");
        this.startX = 0;   
        this.sLeft = 0;   
        this.index = 0;
        this.curLeft = 0; 
        this.disX = 0;    
        this.wrap.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
            _this.fnStart();
        }, false);
    }
    Slider.prototype.fnStart = function (e) {
        var _this = this;
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        this.startX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
        this.sLeft = this.wrap.style.transform ? - parseInt(/\d+/.exec(this.wrap.style.transform)[0]) : 0;
        this.wrap.style.transition = "none";
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", function() {
            _this.fnMove();
        }, false);
        document.addEventListener("touchend", function() {
            _this.fnEnd();
        }, false);
    }
    Slider.prototype.fnMove = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        this.disX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - this.startX;
        // console.log(this.disX);
        this.curLeft = this.disX + this.sLeft;
        this.wrap.style.transform = "translateX(" + this.curLeft + "px)";
    }
    Slider.prototype.fnEnd = function (e) {
        if ( this.disX > 100 ) {
            if ( this.index != 0) {
                this.index -= 1;
            }
        }
        if ( this.disX < -100 ) {
            if ( this.index < this.slider.length - 1) {
                this.index += 1;
            }
        }
        console.log(this.disX);
        this.wrap.style.transition = "0.5s";
        this.wrap.style.transform = "translateX(" + (- this.index*this.slider[0].offsetWidth) + "px)";
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        var box1 = new Slider("test");
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Here's the url you can preview if you can open it:
[NotGeekAtAll.github.io/demo/touches-object.html](http://NotGeekAtAll.github.io/demo/touches-object.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you attach new event on every `touchstart`. You nee to move your `touchmove` and `touchend` event attachments in constructor function:

```js
        function Slider(id) {
            var _this = this;
            this.wrap = document.getElementById(id);
            this.slider = this.wrap.getElementsByTagName("li");
            this.startX = 0;
            this.sLeft = 0;
            this.index = 0;
            this.curLeft = 0;
            this.disX = 0;
            this.wrap.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
                _this.fnStart();
            }, false);
            document.addEventListener("touchmove", _this.fnMove.bind(this), false);
            document.addEventListener("touchend", _this.fnEnd.bind(this), false);
        }
        Slider.prototype.fnStart = function (e) {
            var _this = this;
            e = e || window.event;
            e.preventDefault();
            this.startX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX;
            this.sLeft = this.wrap.style.transform ? - parseInt(/\d+/.exec(this.wrap.style.transform)[0]) : 0;
            this.wrap.style.transition = "none";

        }
        Slider.prototype.fnMove = function (e) {
            e = e || window.event;
            this.disX = e.changedTouches[0].pageX - this.startX;
            // console.log(this.disX);
            this.curLeft = this.disX + this.sLeft;
            this.wrap.style.transform = "translateX(" + this.curLeft + "px)";
        }
        Slider.prototype.fnEnd = function (e) {
            if ( this.disX > 100 ) {
                if ( this.index != 0) {
                    this.index -= 1;
                }
            }
            if ( this.disX < -100 ) {
                if ( this.index < this.slider.length - 1) {
                    this.index += 1;
                }
            }
            console.log(this.disX);
            this.wrap.style.transition = "0.5s";
            this.wrap.style.transform = "translateX(" + (- this.index*this.slider[0].offsetWidth) + "px)";

        }
        window.onload = function () {
            var box1 = new Slider("test");
        }
```

```css
            body { margin: 0; }
            .box { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
            ul,li { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; }
            ul { width: 500%; overflow: hidden; transition: .5s; }
            li { width: 20%; float: left; }
            li { font-size: 40px; color: #fff; text-align: center; line-height: 150px; }
            li:nth-of-type(1) { background: orange; }
            li:nth-of-type(2) { background: red; }
            li:nth-of-type(3) { background: pink; }
            li:nth-of-type(4) { background: green; }
            li:nth-of-type(5) { background: #333; }
```

```html
        <div class="box">
            <ul id="test">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```